# Solve $x^2-(6+7i)x-4+20i=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Solve $x^2-(6+7i)x-4+20i=0$

I probably do too many substitutions, but here is my attempt:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pqze4iagbo3nics/QhvkBcuZsH

Comment: why don't you simply use quadratic formula to find the roots?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation

Answer (score 3):

Hint:This factors into (quadratic formula):

$$(x -4(1+i))(x-(2+3i)) = 0$$

Comment: Short and simple! +1

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Substitute 
$$
x = a+bi
$$
in your equation, and find $a,b$ by comparing coefficients.

Comment: That would give me a system of equations looking like this: $2ab-6b-7a+20=0$ and $a^2-b^2-6a+7b-4=0$.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommand going stright forward, here it a techinal solution $$x^2-(6+7i)-4+20i\Rightarrow\begin{align}x_{1,2}=\frac{6+7i\pm\sqrt{36-49+84i+16-80i}}{2}=\frac{6+7i\pm\sqrt{3+4i}}{2}=\frac{6+7i\pm\sqrt{5cis{166.91}}}{2}=\frac{6+7i\pm\sqrt 5cis83.46}{2}=\frac{6+7i\pm (0.56+2.17i)}{2}\end{align}$$  I used one time conversion to polar and then back. from here it's fine I guess.

**EDIT**:
A) $e^{i\theta}=cis(\theta)\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$. it appears to be a really useful fact (helps in many other exercies).

B)In your solution you claimed $3+4i=5cis(53.13)$ but in degrees $\arctan\frac 4 3=166.91^\circ$ and by de moiver identity, $cis(\theta)^{\frac 1 n}=cis(\frac \theta n)$, and that's why we got $cis\frac {166.91} 2=cis83.46$.

Comment: Assuming _cis_ is polar. I have not seen that notation. What does it mean, on the form $re^{i \phi}$

Comment: I find $3+4i=5e^{53.13i}$ using degrees and not radians.

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: Well, I'm not allowed a calculator. So how would I handle the arctan(4/3)?

Comment: if you dont have caluclator you can also solve a four equalation system: We know the coefficient of $x^2$ is 1 so we can assume we can display the equalartion to something in shape of $(x-z_1)(x-z_2)\quad z_1,z_2\in\mathbb C$ and we need to find $z_1,z_2$. You know that $z_1\cdot z_2=-4+20i$ and so on, if you continue, you can compute the solutions for the equlation without using calculator.

Comment: 4 equation? Where do you get the last 2 from? I get $z_1 \cdot z_2=-2+20i$ and $z_1 + z_2=6+7i$

Comment: Is the answer 1+i/2 and 1-i/2 ?